# Using onInterceptTouchEvent in a class that extends Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I have Fragment with a View which contains some clickable elements (ToggleButtons and a GridView).

I have set an onTouchListener on the View which I use to detect simple swipe gestures, this works perfectly well as long as the swipe doesn't start on any of the clickable items. I would like the swipe to work regardless of where it starts.

I understand that the ToggleButtons and GridView are probably consuming the touch event and in classes which extend ViewGroup I could override onInterceptTouchEvent or dispatchTouchEvent in subclasses of Activity.

Any ideas how I could deal with this situation when extending Fragment?

The closest I've found here is: [Android adding onInterceptTouchEvent to a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475812/android-adding-onintercepttouchevent-to-a-fragment) Unfortunately there have been no replies to this question.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: `onInterceptTouchEvent` is a method of `ViewGroup`, not `Activity`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was referring to dispatchTouchEvent with regard to Activity.

Comment: so you should override `ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent`

Comment: I don't understand how can I do that when my class extends Fragment.

Comment: see onCreateView, your class extends Fragment but it has to create a root View somehow

Comment: The penny has finally dropped thanks for your hints @pskink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got there in the end.

I create a subclass of `RelativeLayout` which is the root of my layout and then within this I override `onInterceptTouchEvent`.

```
public class RootLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public RootLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RootLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RootLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then replace the RelativeLayout in my xml with the new subclass.

```
<com.walker.leigh.dipswitch2.RootLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: incomplete solution